# RoR error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments.micropost_id: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."micropost_id" = 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am developing an app with users where they each have set of microposts displayed on their pages. I am trying to add comments to these microposts. Every time I visit localhost:3000/users/(user_id_#). The user_id was 2 in the error given in the title.

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments.micropost_id: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."micropost_id" = 2

This error only comes when the user has microposts to show. Otherwise it just shows their blank page. The error comes from this view for app/views/users/show.html.erb This view renders this partial, where the error occurs in line 13.

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   micropost.content %>
  <% end %>

  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p>
      <b>Commenter:</b>
      <%= comment.commenter %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Comment:</b>
      <%= comment.body %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
  <%= form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Here is my comment.rb file

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :micropost
  attr_accessible :body, :user_id

end
```

and my micropost.rb file

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

and my comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to micropost_path(@micropost)
  end

end
```

and finally my microposts_controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end


  def new
    @micropost = Micropost.new(params[:micropost])
  end

  def show

    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])


  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @micropost.nil?
    end
end


    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
      def create
        @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
        @comment = @micropost.comments.create(params[:comment])
        redirect_to micropost_path(@micropost)
      end

    end
```

also here is the users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, 
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])

  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

from the error it sounds like the @micropost isnt being initialized in the microposts_controller.rb file under def show. but I think it is? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

also here is app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="span8">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the create comments migration

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :user_id
      t.text :body
      t.references :micropost_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :comments, :micropost_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The error makes it sound like you haven't made a migration to add micropost_id to comment and migrated the database, so I'd start there.

Your migration shows that you are using

```
t.references :micropost_id
```

However t.references accepts a model name, not a foreign_key, so change it to

```
t.references :micropost
```

or change references to an integer for micropost_id, either should give you the result you want.

You may need to do `rake db:reset` to get everything back to where you want it after you fix the migration.

Comment: hmm. I tried that, ran rake db:migrate and nothing changed. I still got the error wrong. I added my comments migration code to the end. Is that what you were talking about

Comment: When you go into Rails c and do a find on a Micropost, what comes out?

Comment: I tried changing it to just :micropost, but it still didnt work. Should I take the _id off of the :micropost in add_index? Also, I am trying to figure out how to find it with the console. Ill let you know when I do

Comment: Ok I figured it out. If I go into rails c and do a Micropost find it gets everything including the micropost_id, user_id, created_at, and content. In other words that works.

Comment: What comes out of `Comment.first`

Comment: Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" LIMIT 1
 => nil

Comment: Just put `Comment` into the console. It should spit out the schema for that model like so: `Workout(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, date: date, time: time, maximum_size: integer, trainer_id: integer) `

Comment: yeah thats what it did. Here is the output: Comment(id: integer, commenter: string, body: text, post_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 
How can this help me fix my error?

Comment: Notice how comment doesn't have a micropost_id foreign key? That's your problem. Either make a migration to add it, or fix your current migration, delete your development database, an re rake